# Proper Namespaces for Public API

Tags: c#, java, api, namespaces

I'm trying to figure out how to properly use namespaces when creating a public API out of a large heap of implementation code.

I'm writing an API to put a friendly public face on all of the code my company has created in order to hack around problems in our most frequently used framework.

The root namespace of my new project is called 'FrameworkSDK'.

Under FrameworkSDK, I have FrameworkSDK.CompanyNameLibrary, which is where all of the implementation code my company has created resides.

I'm attempting to write PublicFacingAPI, which would ideally put a nice face on top of FrameworkSDK.CompanyNameLibrary, so that new developers could start using it instantly, etc.

In what namespace should I put my new PublicFacingAPIcode?

Should it be place in FrameworkSDK.CompanyNameLibrary.PublicFacingAPI?  Then whenever developers import this dll, that would be an absurd using statement.

I could place the code in the FrameworkSDK namespace, but then all of my public classes would need to include the using statement using FrameworkSDK.CompanyNameLibrary or using FrameworkSDK.CompanyNameLibrary.SubNameSpace.

Where should this code go?

Thank you

Comment: First up, "SDK" is a really weird root namespace. Why have you got it there to start with? And why would developers interested in a *public* API want to use something with the name "internal" in it?

Comment: yeah, edited out the word internal, realized that was strange.

Comment: Okay, that makes a bit more sense. I still think that "SDK" should die as a root namespace.

Comment: fair enough, updated to FrameworkSDK.  Is this still bad?  The original thinking was that people would just import FrameworkSDK for their code, but that's when I relized I may have the concept of sub namespaces all jumbled.

Comment: See my answer for what I'd suggest...

Answer (score 1):

I don't find SDK.CompanyNameLibrary.CompanyInternalAPI to be so ridiculous. It's a bit long, but it's descriptive and anyone using the dll will know exactly what they're getting.

Comment: wouldn't that attact people to instead use using statements like 
using SDK.CompanyNameLibrary?

And I imagine most if not all of the classes in that namespace should be internal or private, so as to limit confusion when importing the dll...

any and all help appreciated

Comment: Not really. If you're working with any kind of large-scale system, eventually you're going to have a multitude of namespaces to work with. I feel that the best way to deal with this is to choose your namespaces intelligently in such a way that they accurately reflect what they contain. SDK.CompanyNameLibrary.CompanyInternalAPI tells the implementer that they are getting the company's internal API for whatever library they are using. Although I would probably drop the SDK as it isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need a different namespace for the public-facing part. Make *everything* as friendly as you can, and for bits that really ought to be hidden, keep them as internal types.

I would then drop the "SDK" part, and change to something like:

```
CompanyName.BclPlusPlus
```

or some similar project name which gives the impression of enhancing the core .NET framework. I would definitely separate out the company name as a "root".

Comment: So put everything into one namespace, and simply make things internal / public?  That means I'm going to have ~hundred classes all in one folder in the project, only maybe 25-30 of which are going to be marked public.  Is that really a good practice?  Seems hard to organize...

Comment: If you've got several hundred classes, that sounds like it should potentially not be in one namespace - but that shouldn't be determined by "public vs internal" - it should be determined by purpose.

Comment: Right, I figured one namespace for the public facing materials, and one for the implementation, which is the bulk of the work.  Also, that should have said ~100, not several hundred, apologies

Comment: Even 100 suggests you should be able to break it down more sensibly. If these are meant to be replacements or enhancements to the normal BCL, I'd take the cue from that - so for example, a stream helper class could be in `CompanyName.BclPlusPlus.IO` to match `System.IO`.